# How to install miktex for latex in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation

How do I Install miktex package in ubuntu 17.04?
I had downloaded a file of miktex but i don't know how to install with it..
I am new to ubuntu and i have a project to complete in latex for which miktex packages are needed.
So please help me with any suggestion to install it.

Comment: Why miktex? It's normaly for Windows and MAC not for Linux. I would rather suggest TexLive... Anyway you could try to open it using wine.
What are miktex packages? LaTex only requires LaTex packages usually ;) ... could you tell us what file format you downloaded and from where?

Comment: sudo apt-get install texlive-full;
sudo apt-get install texmaker  ;
I used this command and installed texlive but I could not find all the packages like picture packege, so my friend suggessted me to install miktex for additional packages.

Comment: Someone may correct me but as far as I know miktex is nothing more than a package manager for LaTex .. and you never need texlive full ... Rather install only texlive and texmaker. There's than an option to automatically download packages on the fly wherever needed while compiling a Latex document

Answer (score 1):

You need to first register the repository which contains the MiKTeX installation package(s):

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
    echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
    sudo apt-get update
```

there are some dependencies issues(This problem occurs only in ubuntu 17.04) when you try to install directly. Hence you have to manually download the libraries (deb files) after you download them from the following sites (in my case libhunspell-1.3, libpng12-0) if you have more dependencies you can search and install from this [link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search)

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libhunspell-1.3-0/download
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download

then use dpkg -i "path to the file" to manually install all the files

then `apt install miktex`

Comment: I would try to explain a little more of what you're trying to accomplish with the code part...

Comment: added comments..

Answer (score 0):

From [the MiKTeX website](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx):

### How to install MiKTeX

#### Ubuntu 16.04, Linux Mint 18 or higher (64-bit)

You need to first register the repository which contains the MiKTeX
installation package(s):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install MiKTeX:

```
sudo apt-get install miktex
```